# crash due to camera in android

Tags: android, camera, crash

We created an android native app and it is crashing under certain conditions. It has to do with the camera certainly, but not exactly sure what it could be.

I would like to highlight that I am not an android developer (I develop mostly in python) but I wonder if the android experts out there can provide some context about the error.

Here is the stack trace from the google play console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters (Native Method)
  at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters (Camera.java:1946)
  at identidata.br.camera.CameraPicturePreview.surfaceChanged (CameraPicturePreview.java:75)
  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow (SurfaceView.java:611)
  at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw (SurfaceView.java:181)
  at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw (ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2000)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1073)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:5985)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:767)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:580)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:550)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:753)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5912)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1405)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Answer (score 0):

Android Camera API documents that [Camera.setParameters()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setParameters(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters)) may throw a RuntimeException if something goes wrong. Taking into account the Android fragmentation, you have a chance to trigger some hidden incompatibility with any innocent call to setParameters(). Therefore, I strongly recommend to always `try … catch` RuntimeException around this call.

I won't be surprised if your specific crash happens because you try to set unsupported preview size when you process the [surfaceChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html#surfaceChanged(android.view.SurfaceHolder,%20int,%20int,%20int)) callback. This callback comes with **width** and **height** parameters, and it is a natural temptation to use these values for [Camera.Parameters.setPreviewSize()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewSize(int,%20int)). Unfortunately, this won't work. You must always choose one of the values from the list of [supported Preview Sizes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes()).